# pass lambda with capture as a parameter of ANOTHER lambda, possible?

Tags: c++, lambda

Is it possible to pass lambda function **with capture** as a parameter of another lambda function?

```
int a=3;
auto func_1=[&]()->{a=4;};
auto func_2=[&](  ?????  fParam   ){  fParam(); }; //what is a proper ?????
func_2(func_1);
```

(I want to use it to do some fancy thing.)

### Edit

Thank for many solutions.  I have learned a lot.

In original question, I forgot to mention that **func_2** also want to receive other functions e.g. **func_2(func_1a)**, **func_2(func_1b)**, etc.

Therefore, **decltype** is one of correct answers for the original question, but not fulfil my demand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what `auto` is for:

```
auto func_2=[&](auto fParam   ){  fParam(); };
```

Your compiler must have at least C++14-level language support.

EDIT: with C++11, the following appears to work:

```
auto func_2=[&](decltype(func_1)  fParam   ){  fParam(); };
```

Comment: Yep, specifically because lambdas are generated function objects of unique but anonymous types.

Comment: For C++11, `std::function` works. Of course if this is only ever being called with `func_1`, capturing works better.

Comment: Seriously?  It works!  But it is scary when the parameter type is "auto".   Can I avoid it? Thank!

Comment: @javaLover First tell us why you _think_ it's scary and why you _think_ you should try to avoid it. Then we can tell you why you're wrong ;-) But no, in seriousness though, I guess it can leave you open to accidentally passing something else, and that's where the `decltype` idea is pretty nice. Personally I'd just use `auto` and trust myself, but there's nothing wrong with wanting the compiler to check things for you.

Comment: @javaLover Without the Concepts TS, not really. With the Concepts TS, you could replace `auto` with a `Callable` concept. It will still be generic, but it will give you proper error messages if you pass an `int` or a string

Comment: @underscore_d  I thought "auto" is scary, because "auto" is generally not allowed to be type of parameter for "normal" function.  The reason is that signature of a function, including lambda, should be explicit declared, not sneakingly hidden by "auto" ... same as everything (most) else in C++.

Comment: @javaLover It's not much different from the existing `template` model, it's just less noisy. Basically, (fictional syntax) `template< typename T > [&]( T && fParam ) { fParam(); }` would be more "normal", but it wouldn't be any more explicit.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yeah, in fact, lambda parameter type deduction is simply defined as though the user had typed `template<template-params>
ret operator()(params) { body }` with `template-params` accounting for any named arguments whose type is declared as `auto`.

Answer (score 3):

As Chris said in a comment, you could use `std::function` for this. Given your concerns about `auto`'s inherent lack of type-checking, this has the advantage that it lets you restrict to callables of a particular signature, since `std::function` is a template that is instantiated once for each signature in your program, and template instantiations aren't convertible. It can effortlessly hold a lambda, just as it can any other callable object.

This level of type-checking is probably more generally useful than the `decltype(oneSpecificLambda)` version, but that's useful to know about!

Combining this with the other answers, you can thus choose to restrict your passed parameter at the point of declaration, in at least 3 ways:

- not at all = `auto`,
- to a particular function signature = `std::function< T_Return(T_Args...) >`,
- or to a specific single function object = `decltype(oneSpecificLambda)`, since each lambda is a distinct unnamed type, again not convertible.

Personally, I would probably just use `auto` in this case and trust myself not to accidentally pass anything else. But it's good to have so many options!

Comment: This is a complete answer with a perfect explanation.   I hope I can also accept it.

Comment: @javaLover Stack Exchange sites only allow selection of one answer (the one most recently clicked to accept), with the closest thing to a 'runner up' being if you award a Bounty. Please accept whichever answer you think best addresses your question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this will work too, but as Sam Varshavchik said, if C++14 is available then just use auto.

```
int a=3;
auto func_1=[&]()->{a=4;};
auto func_2=[&](  decltype(func_1) fParam ){  fParam(); };
func_2(func_1);
```

Comment: If your `func_2` is not "reusable", and can only be used with `func_1`, why not just make it a capture-list parameter?

Comment: @KABoissonneault You're going to have to ask the OP that, but it may be that it has to be used in some other code so he's stuck needing a lambda function that takes another lambda as a parameter.  I have no idea myself.

Comment: @KABoissonneault   Yes, in my fantasy version, func_2 is reusable.   func_2 is a tiny multi-task manager.  func_1 is a big task to be split.

Comment: @javaLover Then I guess this answer won't work, isn't it? Since `func_2` can't know the type of `func_1`, and needs to handle other lambdas.

Comment: @javaLover ...and if that's the case, perhaps consider what Chris suggested and I've fleshed out in my answer. ;-)

Comment: @KABoissonneault  You are correct, func_2 can't receive others lambdas,  thank!